# How do you stack images with aligned output?

Tags: html, css

I've got these posts which are images and output I'd like to stack in a column, but the divs are stuck on top of each other. I'd like to have them stacked with a bit of margin between them. How do you stack images with aligned output?

```
<hr />
<div id="listingwrapper">
   <div style="float:left;">
       <img src="gateway/imgs/stock/profilechick.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div style="float:left; width: 246px;">
      <span style="color:white;"><b>Wicked awesome chick goes to the</b></span><br/>
   </div><br/>
   <div>    
      <span style="color:white;"><i>600 views</i></span>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="listingwrapper" style="clear:both;">
    <div style="float:left;">
       <img src="gateway/imgs/stock/profilechick.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width: 246px;">
      <span style="color:white;"><b>Wicked awesome chick goes to the</b></span><br/>
    </div><br/>
    <div>    
      <span style="color:white;"><i>600 views</i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference between stacking in a column and stacking on top of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whknfLbd/1/) here

`#listingwrapper {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
}`